# Highcharts Pyramid - same size of segments - despite the data value

Tags: charts, highcharts

I was wondering if it would be possible to ignore the sizes of segments in highcharts pyramid. I would like all segments to be of the same size despite the value. The reason is that sometimes differences between values may be quite significant and value of 1 - even being extremely important, becomes invisible when the next value is 500. Also, would like to be able to add a legend if possible. It would be nice to set a minimum size of a segment if not possible to get dynamic sizing disabled.

Thanks for your help!

Pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add additional data according to which the height of the segment will be calculated. Next, use `keys` option to map the values and show the right one in a tooltip and data label:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.realY}</b><br/>'
},

series: [{
    ...
    keys: ['name', 'realY', 'y'],
    dataLabels: {
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.realY:,.0f})',
        ...
    },
    data: [
        ['Website visits', 15654, 1],
        ['Downloads', 4064, 1],
        ['Requested price list', 1987, 1],
        ['Invoice sent', 976, 1],
        ['Finalized', 846, 1]
    ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e83fatk2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.keys

Comment: Hi @sampak, You can set `marginRight` to fix it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0upohkq5/